# Norm of ideal belongs to the ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $D$ is any number ring (i.e. $D=\mathbb Q(\alpha), \alpha \in \mathbb C$). Let $I$ be any ideal of $D$. Show that $N(I)=|D/I|$ belongs to $I$.

How to start? is there a specific fact will be helpful here

Comment: You seem to be confusing the notions of `number field` ($\mathbf Q(\alpha)$) and its `ring of integers`, i.e. the integral closure of $\mathbf Z$ in  $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$. A number field, as any field, has only two ideals.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I got confused . Thank you .